# Quotation Marks when the variable is printed or echoed

Tags: php, html

I'm getting the variable within `textbox` as `$Dataprefix=hello`, but what I want is to show the values within quotes as `"hello"`
Here's my code.

```
 Data File Prefix Name:&nbsp; <input size="5" name="dataprefix" type="text"  value="<?php echo $Dataprefix;?>">
```

and it shows value within `textbox` as `hello`

Comment: No, I know how to display a php variable into html ,I just don't know how to display it within quotation marks

Comment: It'll work the way you have shown. If not then you need to update your post with more relevant code or error why its not working

Comment: @MaryE Sorry but your question is completely unclear. You already put your variable between quotes. What do you want? Escape them if present in the PHP variable ?

Comment: The program will show hello and I want "hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then try this way it'll work for you

```
Data File Prefix Name:&nbsp; <input size="5" name="dataprefix" type="text"  value='"<?php echo $Dataprefix;?>"'>
                                                                                   ^^                        ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `echo`. Try this

```
Data File Prefix Name:&nbsp; <input size="5" name="dataprefix" type="text"  value="<?php echo $Dataprefix;?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` to print variable

```
value="<?php echo $Dataprefix;?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable wrapped quotation marks to be displayed then :

```
echo '"'.$Dataprefix.'"';
```

If you only want to echo the variable when it satisfies "hello" :

```
echo ($Dataprefix === 'hello'? $Dataprefix : '' );
```

If this isn't what you are looking for then I would recommend rephrasing your question.